# Cannot unset http_proxy

Tags: xubuntu, proxy

I have **Xubuntu** and I can't unset the http_**proxy** variable.
And I want to unset it because i can't downloading now.

I try to do

> unset http_proxy

or

> export http_proxy=

Comment: What is the output of `echo $http_proxy`?

Comment: Nothing but if I use sudo apt-get install <Something>

Its says: "0% [Connecting to 10.13.48.254 (10.13.48.254)]"

Or: "E: Some packages could not be authenticated"

Answer (score 1):

**From the command-line:**

apt-get uses configuration settings from `/etc/apt/apt.conf`. You have set your proxy in `/etc/apt/apt.conf`. To remove the proxy for apt, remove the proxy from `/etc/apt/apt.conf` by opening the file as follows:

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/apt.conf
```

enter your password and remove the lines containing the proxy and then save and exit and restart your installation.

**From the GUI:**

You can also do this from **System settings -> Network -> Network Proxy** and then setting the *Method* to "None" and applying settings system-wide.